# Authentic hadith on Muhammad ﷺ reciting complete Qur'an to zaid ibn thabit

Tags: hadith, reference-request

I have heard from various sources that during the last time of prophet Muhammad ﷺ in this world jibrail (السلام عليه) recited complete Qur'an to Muhammad ﷺ and he ﷺ recited it completely to zaid ibn thabit (رضي الله ﺗﻌﺎﻟﯽٰ عنه)
So, is there any authentic hadith that says this
And what about 7 ahruf?

Comment: The matter is exactly the opposite than what you mentioned. Jibril reviewed twice the prophets recitation according to some ahadith ...

Comment: Thats why I am asking the authentic event

Comment: Maybe you should should open your question to hadith with low authenticity ratings to get a trace to the source.

Comment: First of all the hadith you seem to be referring to about the last time our Prophet and Jibreel revised the qur'an was in Ramadan (see for example [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3554)) so it was a couple of months before the death of the prophet while the last verses of the qur'an were only revealed a few days before his death. So this revision only included the at the time actual complet qur'an not the one we have at hands now.